# How to build cscope database for AOSP source?

Tags: android-source, cscope

I am using `cscope -b -R` command from AOSP root directory to build its database. I kept cscope  running for more than 9 hours but its database is not created. There is no cscope.out file there. Is it stuck somewhere ?

Comment: Check this : https://nativeguru.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/aosp-code-navigation-with-cscope/

Comment: @Lakindu Thanks. This helped. Can you post as answer So I can mark it .

Comment: That's great! I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this blog post : https://nativeguru.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/aosp-code-navigation-with-cscope/

You can first create the `cscope.files` file that contains all the file paths that contain the code you want to navigate, then use `cscope` command as below.

```sh
$ cd <aosp_root_dir>
$ find . -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -and -not \( -path "./out/*" -o -path "./prebuilts/*" -o -path "./external/*" -o -path "./dalvik/*"  -o -path "./ndk/*"  \) > cscope.files
$ cscope -b -q -k
```